# Where to put the logic for delete queries

Tags: design-patterns

I have seperated my model logic into "entity", "mapper" and "service". I started of by putting my database delete queries in the mapper, but the more I think about it, it feels like a service.

I'm unsure though, mayby there is some other layer I don't know of that would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely where you place the logic for physical changes to the database depends entirely on the particulars of your design.  If you have UPDATE and INSERT statements in your "mapper", having DELETE is entirely appropriate.  Conversely, if they're in the service, then having them there is also entirely appropriate.

What's important is that YOUR software makes sense, not that it adheres to someone else's stated model.

(Although, fwiw, I would expect your "entity" classes be unaware of the physical database, your "mapper" classes to translate db result sets to and from to entity classes, and your "service" classes to contain all actual db code, from the SELECT and UPDATE to the INSERT and DELETE.)

Comment: I agree that consistency is the key. I like to discus the matter sense I don't feel my approch for the moment is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would put delete logic in the service layer. The entity and the mapper objects do not have any responsibility regards deletion, but the service layer is a perfect fit.

There are patterns such as Active Record, where the entity may interact with the database (in Ruby on Rails for example), but in your case, stick with the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

When i worked on web service I made ORM generic class which was able to insert, edit, delete and select. Then I subclass this class. Subclasses have attributes like fields in tables of my database.

If i want to delete some object which I have i simply call (int PHP):

```
$object->delete;
```

If i create an object and want to add it to database i call:

```
$object = new ObjectModel($pdo); /// subclass of ORM class (TableName: Object)
$object->name = "name";
$object->age = 15;
$object->save();
```

And ORM class has `isLoaded` key and when I called `save()` it knows if call insert or update method. In this case insert.

This generic class should call all database-related method.

Comment: I have worked with a few ORM's before. Some realy sweet tools are out there. But they slow thinks down. Not a big issue in most cases, but for this project I'm working on now it is.